# web.api cannot test action

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have created a Web.API, MVC application but ran into some trouble when trying to test it. I get this error:

> "{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:60104/api/order/SayWhat/33'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'order'."}"

OrderController

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public string SayWhat(string quoteName)
{
    return "Hello World " + quoteName;
}
```

WebApiConfig

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultPostApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{quote}"
);

config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

Comment: Is your controller class public?

Comment: Yes the controller is public

Comment: The configuration and controller look fine. You should show some more code. Are you sure your app is running on that port? Do you have any other route for APi or MVC?

Answer (score 3):

Use below code in WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{quoteName}",
            defaults: new { quoteName = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

And In Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
    [ActionName("SayWhat")]
    public string SayWhat(string quoteName)
    {
        return "Hello World " + quoteName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add the attribute "ActionName" to the function.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet()]
[ActionName("SayWhat")]
public string SayWhat(string quoteName)
{
    return Convert.ToString("Hello World ") + quoteName;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my WebApiConfig with everything I got in this one. I also tried the actionname attribute, but that dod not help. Still the same error..

Comment: Ok, I have found the solution change this: routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{action}/{quote}" with this routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{action}/{quotename}"

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that it is not seeing the Order controller.

> "No type was found that matches the controller named 'order'."

Given that you indicated that you indeed have an `OrderController` then one possibility is that the controller is not of the correct type as the framework looks for types that inherit from `ApiController`.

Make sure the controller is of the correct type

```
public class OrderController : ApiController {    
    //GET api/Order/saywhat/33
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public string SayWhat(string quote) {
        return "Hello World " + quote;
    }
}
```